# Python: dictionary to store pattern and its results

Tags: python, dictionary

I came to a problem where i need to store some pattern and it's matches. 
I want to have something like below

```
dict1={}
a=range(1,11)
dict1["range1-11"]=a
```

But, it is throwing below errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I am actually looking for

```
dict1["range-1-11"] to print
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Surely Possible :)

Can somebody pls help me out

Comment: Could you show your desired output please? At the moment it is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks like this is not possible"?  Tracebacks?  Current results vs intended results?

Comment: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" - please show the *actual* code .. anyway, I would create a custom hashable/comparable type to represent these ranges/patterns, which can then be used as a key.

Comment: Thanks. this works. I think i was doing some wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What you had should work just fine already for python 2.x.  For python3, you will need to change it:

```
dict1 = {}
a = list(range(1,11))
dict1["range1-11"] = a
```

More easily extensible will be to factor out the start and stop, something like this:

```
ranges = ((1, 11),)
dict1 = {'range{}-{}'.format(a, b): list(range(a, b)) for a, b in ranges}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was some thing wrong. Below things works perfectly

```
>>>
>>> dict1={} 
>>> a=range(1,11)
>>> dict1["range1-11"]=a
>>> dict1["range1-11"]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> b=range(11,21)
>>> b
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
>>> dict1["range11-21"]=b
>>> dict1["range11-21"]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Thanks all

Answer (score -2):

What you ask is somewhat unclear, but you may want something like:

```
dict1 = {}
a = "range(1,11)"
dict1[a] = eval(a)
```